# In App Purchase restore Not Working - iOS Swift StoreKit

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am using [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) to handle my in app purchasing.  I have one non-consumable in-app purchase.  I am unable to restore the purchase.  I am testing this on a release version of my app where I have been charged before for it, but it will not restore.  The code I am using to call SwiftyStoreKit is as follows:

```
SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true) { results in
    if results.restoreFailedProducts.count > 0 {
        print("Restore Failed: \(results.restoreFailedProducts)")
    }
    else if results.restoredProducts.count > 0 {
        print("Restore Success: \(results.restoredProducts)")
        self.defaults?.set(true, forKey: "UnlockApp")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "transition"), object: nil)
        self.dismissView()
    } else {
        print("Nothing to Restore")
    }
}
```

As you can see I set a user default in order to unlock features in the app, but this never triggers it always comes back with "Nothing to Restore"

Has anyone dealt with this, or know a possible reason for this behavior?

Edit: This is on a physical device, on a release version (not sandboxed purchase)

Comment: This can happen when running in the simulator. The simulators do no fully support Store Kit and restoring or attempting to purchase items can come back as failed or an error. It would be worth trying on a device to see if the problem continues.

Comment: I will edit my question, but this is on a physical device on a release version (not sandboxes purchase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was when i have a developer version on the phone, i must:

1. Uninstall the developer version
2. Restart iPhone
3. Download production version from app store

Then the restore purchase option will work

Comment: Did you test with a sandbox user?